Save video output to a new file each time a button is pressed? - Human Dashcam Project
Apologies if this is out of format, this is my first time on Stack Exchange!
I've been trying to build a project that functions like a real-world equivalent of Nvidia's Shadowplay feature--a camera that's always recording and deleting frames on a loop until a button is pressed, and a set of frames from the last seven seconds are saved to an SD card to be viewed later. Someone else already beat me to this project, but I am attempting to modify it so that it does not require a phone to be used as an SSH server.
The original project can be viewed here:
https://www.instructables.com/Film-in-the-Past/ with the source code for the Raspberry Pi below:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

print(cap.get(3)) #width
print(cap.get(4)) #height
print(cap.get(5)) # fps

frameList = []

numberOfSavedFrames = 30*7

i=0
vidNb = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()


    frameList.append(frame)

    if(len(frameList) > numberOfSavedFrames):
#        cv2.imshow('frame',frameList[len(frameList)-1])
        frameList.pop(0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if(input_state == False):
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30.0, (640, 480)) #resolution for video and parameters for output are defined here
        for frame in frameList:
            out.write(frame)            # I BELIVE THAT THE PROBLEM IS EITHER ON THIS LINE
        vidNb += 1                      # OR ON THIS LINE
        
        
    i += 1                              #OR MAYBE ON THIS ONE

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I'm trying to make a change so that when the button is pressed, a new 'output.avi' (or .mp4) file is created incrementally, with each file being named something like 'output1.avi', 'output2.avi', and so on.
Getting OpenCV to work was a huge mess in and of itself, but importing an image where it was already set up solved the problem, so I'm going to leave it alone.
I have tried editing the code to this to solve the output problem:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

print(cap.get(3)) #width
print(cap.get(4)) #height
print(cap.get(5)) # fps

frameList = []
numberOfSavedFrames = 30*7

i=0
vidNb = 0
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    frameList.append(frame)

    if len(frameList) > numberOfSavedFrames:
        frameList.pop(0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
        # Generate new filename for the output video
        output_filename = 'output_' + str(vidNb) + '.avi'
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_filename, fourcc, 30.0, (640, 480))
        for frame in frameList:
            out.write(frame)
        vidNb += 1
        out.release()  # Release the video writer after writing
        
        # Clear frameList for the next video
        frameList.clear()
        
    i += 1

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

But this resulted in a new file being created for each frame, which quickly filled up the SD card with empty files. Any help would really be appreciated, and again I am sorry if this does not match the format that this forum requires.

Side note: How exactly is print(cap.get(3)) #width more readable than print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))? And if it isn't, then why are you doing it? (Also, no validation, destroyAllWindows without any windows existing, the useless release calls at the end of the program...)

basically a programming problem, not related to OpenCV. -- your GPIO handling is broken. that's not how to react to a button press event. that triggers, repeatedly, as long as the button is held down. you haven't shown us your circuit diagram either, so who's to know what a low level on the GPIO means? -- perhaps reddit would be a better fit for this. your program needs debugging. on SO, we expect that to have happened already, and for you to know what's wrong exactly, but you don't know how to fix it. there are plenty of subreddits for programming beginners, also raspberry pi.
